# Styling tkinter Scale class

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-scale

Here is the scale I have:

```
    self.volume_slider = tk.Scale(
        self,
        from_=0,
        to=100,
        orient=tk.HORIZONTAL,
        background="#fdfdfe",
        highlightbackground="#fdfdfe",
        highlightcolor="#fdfdfe",
        troughcolor="#37b9fe",
        showvalue=False,
        resolution=1,
        bd=0,
        width=7)
```

[image: Scale I have]

But my desired scale is something like this:

[image: Scale I want]

[Edit] How can this be achieved?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/59678715/7432