# Customize the slider scale

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a slider scale in `tkinter` which I created using the code below. I want to customize it to appear like the attached figure. Any ideas to improve it are welcome.

This is what my slider looks like right now:

[image: This is how my slider looks so far]

This is how I want it to look:

[image: I want a slider like this]

```
scaler_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=root, text="Zoom", compound=RIGHT, fg_color="gray40", corner_radius=8).place(x=10, y=15)
var1 = StringVar()
scale = tk.Scale(root, variable=var1, orient='horizontal', bg = "gray45", bd=1,from_=1, to=10, length=100, resolution=1, command=())
scale.place(x=15, y=20)
```

Comment: You might try reading through this to see if it answers your question: https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/styles.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Tkinter slider customization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59678715/python-tkinter-slider-customization). I know it doesn't look exactly the same, but the basic styling principles still apply.

Comment: I think I have seen that but not sure how to integrate it here in this case @SylvesterKruin

Comment: Well, that question, along with the documentation Bryan gave you, should set you on the right track. It might take some time, but once you learn it, you'll be much better at customizing your apps.